# Bulk open multi tab using Google Chrome Console

Tags: google-chrome, console

I want to open several page (nearly 100) using Google Chrome console. I cannot just paste and enter this...

```
window.open("https://www.website1.org", "_blank1"); 
window.open("https://www.website2.com", "_blank2"); 
...
window.open("https://www.website100.com", "_blank100");
```

...because it only open the first one...
Any clue ? Thanks !

Comment: You want it in 100 separate windows, or one window with 100 tabs?

Comment: @Narzard One window with 100 tabs... But if you know how to do it with 100 separate windows, I could use it too :-)